# How do I extract data from GoogleMapsEngineLink in Google Earth kml file to a tabular form?

Tags: google-earth

Basically this GoogleMapsEngineLink ( http://globe.six.nsw.gov.au/kml/nswglobe.kml ) is within the KML file which can be easily opened by google earth and data extracted from this URL get plotted within Google Earth. But I need a means to save this data within a tabular format like excel, so I can import it within my database for further analysis.

The KML file I am talking about has content as

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"

     xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">

     <gx:GoogleMapsEngineLink>

         <href>http://globe.six.nsw.gov.au/nswglobe/</href>    

     </gx:GoogleMapsEngineLink>

</kml>
```

Download link for kml file - http://globe.six.nsw.gov.au/kml/nswglobe.kml

As you can see, this kml file doesn't content the data itself, but just contents this URL link from where data is downloaded. When I open this URL in browser, It asks for google earth plugin. So looks like, It's using some sort of google earth protocols or API calls to deliver the data. My guess is, I would need to either write those API calls manually or either way simulate Google Earth to ask data from this URL and save the data in tabular format like CSV instead of plotting into google earth.
The other way I can think of is, If there is a way to save/export the data loaded in google earth into a file?